# What type of storm cloud is this?

Tags: meteorology, clouds

We have had (and are still experiencing) waves of storms passing through this area of the central Queensland 'Capricornia' coast, Australia.  This area is a subtropical coastal environment, close to sea level.

The following picture is one I took from my the balcony outside my lab (facing east):

[image]

The storm was moving to the north (left) and that part of the sky was a featureless heavy cloud. The conditions were as follows:

**Ambient temperature:** 30C (86F)

**Wind:** strong, to the north

**Conditions:** Heavy rain periods, heavy thunder and lightning, about 10 minutes later, the sky cleared, temperature rose and the wind dropped to barely a breeze.  Numerous cloud-to-ground and cloud-to-cloud lightning was noticed from this cloud formation.

I am leaning towards this being a 'scud cloud', but a local weather-enthusiast claims it was a weakly formed non-rotating wall cloud.

**What type of cloud is this?**

Comment: Do you have any additional pictures of this? I think I am leaning toward it being a non-rotating wall cloud; however, additional pictures would be helpful.

Comment: @L.B. Unfortunately, no - however, to the left was just a uniform grey mass of clouds, to the right was a continuation of the cloud bank.  This was quite a fast moving system.

Comment: The cloud that is slightly triangular was apart of a cloud mass that sat slightly lower than the rest of the clouds didn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a rather difficult time telling how the rest of the cloud structure looks; however, I would tend to believe your weather-enthusiast friend might be correct.

A [wall cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_cloud) - rotating or not - can also be known as a pedestal cloud and is made up of cumulonimbus clouds; generally forming in the strongest part of the storm.
From what I can tell in the picture and judging by the weather that came from it; it sounds like it was a non-rotating wall cloud. [Here](http://www.weather.com/news/news/thats-not-a-tornado-20130307) is an additional reference page that may help you identify it.